# how to get change event on created fields in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery code the creates an quantity text box. Like so

```
<input type="text" value="1000" class="qty" name="[0].Quantity">
```

I wish to add some validation to this text box but can hit the method. I believe i need to utlise Live(). But can't quite figure out how this is implemented.

This is where i'm at

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".qty").change(checkValue);
    });

    function checkValue() {

        alert("on change");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) syntax would look like this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".qty").live('change', checkValue);
});
```

[You can test it a bit here](http://jsfiddle.net/BLjsw/), keep in mind this fires on [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) usually though, you may want the [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) events rather than change if you're looking to do it per character.